# Every Post routes gives 419 page expired error in laravel even if csrf token is there

Tags: php, laravel, apache

My project developed using laravel6 on apache2. It is working properly in my local system.

When I deployed that project in staging server, My project's all routes are working. but all POST routes gives 419 page expired error even if there is CSRF token in every form.

Login screen appears but after I click on submit button post route is called and it gives me 419 error.

I also created one custom route for testing. but it will give same 419 error. In short, my every post route is giving 419 error.

I checked with giving necessary permission to storage folder, cache folder, also changed env configuration setting( SESSION_DOMAIN, SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE). but no any solution worked.

Is there any apache misconfiguration?

Comment: what driver are you using for a session?

Comment: @neel I am using file driver for session

Comment: have you already add @csrf and meta csrf token?

Comment: Yes I have used both @csrf and meta csrf token

Comment: try to use SSL and https on your project

Comment: @ASHafizullah ok I will try with SSL

Comment: tell me the result sir, because i have same problem

Comment: @ASHafizullah with the https and domain it is working

Comment: so its clear now?

Comment: @ASHafizullah yes